# How to fix "ERROR Exception in init...model was aborted because of Read-only object file" with stain/jena-fuseki ? Docker, reasoner, TDB

Tags: docker, dockerfile, jena, fuseki

> "This question was solved by updating Jena Fuseki to latest version (>=v3.11.0). Thanks to [@AndyS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/757100/andys) answer.".

### Summary

I'm setting up a Jena Fuseki Dockerfile with a preconfigured dataset to ease Jena Fuseki configuration for my application.

I'm using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM stain/jena-fuseki:3.10.0

COPY ./db_tdb.ttl /fuseki/configuration/
COPY ./ontology.rules /fuseki/configuration/
COPY ./ontology /fuseki/ontology/
```

Here is the file architecture used:

**-- Dockerfile**      (Dockerfile for building the image)
**-- db_tdb.ttl**      (Configuration file for the dataset)
**-- ontology.rules**  (Define inference rules)
**-- ontology**        (Folder contain ontology files description)
**---- ontFile1.rdf**
**---- ontFile2.rdf**

I build and run my image with following commands:

```
docker build -t myfuseki .
docker run -it -p 3030:3030 -e JVM_ARGS=-Xmx2048M myfuseki:latest
```

I'm getting the following error on running:

```
[2019-09-12 16:14:09] Server     ERROR Exception in initialization: the loading of content into :model was aborted because of Read-only object file
```

What does this error means ? How to fix it?

### Some of what I try

As the "model was aborted because of Read-only object file" I think it could be a file rights issue.

So I tried to change ontology files rights to 777 (not the best idea I know, but was for testing purpose) in the container.

But I still get the same issue.

### File / Errors contents

Here is my `db_tdb.ttl` config file for Jena Fuseki:

```
@prefix : <#> .
@prefix fuseki: <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix tdb: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#> .
@prefix ja: <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#> .

[] rdf:type fuseki:Server ;
 fuseki:services (
 <#service1>
 ) .

## ---------------------------------------------------------------
## Service with only SPARQL query on an inference model.
## Inference model base data in TDB.

<#service1> rdf:type fuseki:Service ;
 fuseki:name "server" ;
 fuseki:serviceQuery "query" ;
 fuseki:serviceUpdate "update" ;
 fuseki:serviceUpload "upload" ;
 fuseki:serviceReadWriteGraphStore "data" ;
 fuseki:serviceReadGraphStore "get" ;
 fuseki:dataset <#dataset>  ;
 .

<#dataset> rdf:type ja:RDFDataset ;
    ja:defaultGraph <#model> ;
    . 

<#model> a ja:InfModel ;
    ja:baseModel <#tdbGraph> ;
    ja:content <#ontFile1> , <#ontFile2>;
    ja:reasoner [
        ja:reasonerURL <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2003/GenericRuleReasoner> ;
        ja:rulesFrom <file:./ontology.rules>
    ] ;
    .

<#tdbGraph> rdf:type tdb:GraphTDB ;
    tdb:dataset <#tdbDataset> ;
    .

<#tdbDataset> rdf:type tdb:DatasetTDB ;
    tdb:location "/fuseki/databases/bemserver" ;
    .

# Ontology files
<#ontFile1> ja:externalContent <file:/fuseki/ontology/ontFile1.rdf> .
<#ontFile2> ja:externalContent <file:/fuseki/ontology/ontFile2.rdf> .
```

Here is the full error:

```
[2019-09-12 16:14:09] Server     ERROR Exception in initialization: the loading of content into :model was aborted because of Read-only object file
[2019-09-12 16:14:09] WebAppContext WARN  Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6e4ea0bd{Apache Jena Fuseki Server,/,file:///jena-fuseki/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE}
org.apache.jena.assembler.exceptions.TransactionAbortedException: the loading of content into :model was aborted because of Read-only object file
  doing:
    root: file:///fuseki/configuration/db_tdb.ttl#model with type: http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#InfModel assembler class: class org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.InfModelAssembler
    root: file:///fuseki/configuration/db_tdb.ttl#dataset with type: http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#RDFDataset assembler class: class org.apache.jena.sparql.core.assembler.DatasetAssembler

        at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ModelAssembler.addContent(ModelAssembler.java:55)
        at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ModelAssembler.open(ModelAssembler.java:44)
        at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.openBySpecificType(AssemblerGroup.java:157)
        at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:144)
        at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$ExpandingAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:93)
        at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:39)
        at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:35)
        at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup.openModel(AssemblerGroup.java:47)
        at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.assembler.DatasetAssembler.createDataset(DatasetAssembler.java:56)
        at org.apache.jena.sparql.core.assembler.DatasetAssembler.open(DatasetAssembler.java:43)
        at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.openBySpecificType(AssemblerGroup.java:157)
        at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$PlainAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:144)
        at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerGroup$ExpandingAssemblerGroup.open(AssemblerGroup.java:93)
        at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:39)
        at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.AssemblerBase.open(AssemblerBase.java:35)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiConfig.getDataset(FusekiConfig.java:345)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiConfig.buildDataService(FusekiConfig.java:299)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiConfig.buildDataAccessPoint(FusekiConfig.java:289)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiConfig.readConfiguration(FusekiConfig.java:272)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.build.FusekiConfig.readConfigurationDirectory(FusekiConfig.java:251)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.webapp.FusekiWebapp.initializeDataAccessPoints(FusekiWebapp.java:226)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.webapp.FusekiServerListener.serverInitialization(FusekiServerListener.java:98)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.webapp.FusekiServerListener.contextInitialized(FusekiServerListener.java:56)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:952)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:558)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:917)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:847)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:287)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.doStart(GzipHandler.java:410)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:416)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:383)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.JettyFusekiWebapp.start(JettyFusekiWebapp.java:138)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd.runFuseki(FusekiCmd.java:372)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.exec(FusekiCmd.java:356)
        at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainMethod(CmdMain.java:93)
        at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:58)
        at jena.cmd.CmdMain.mainRun(CmdMain.java:45)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd$FusekiCmdInner.innerMain(FusekiCmd.java:104)
        at org.apache.jena.fuseki.cmd.FusekiCmd.main(FusekiCmd.java:67)
Caused by: org.apache.jena.tdb.TDBException: Read-only object file
        at org.apache.jena.tdb.base.objectfile.ObjectFileReadonly.write(ObjectFileReadonly.java:28)
        at org.apache.jena.tdb.lib.NodeLib.encodeWrite(NodeLib.java:85)
        at org.apache.jena.tdb.lib.NodeLib.encodeStore(NodeLib.java:73)
        at org.apache.jena.tdb.store.nodetable.NodeTableNative.writeNodeToTable(NodeTableNative.java:172)
        at org.apache.jena.tdb.store.nodetable.NodeTableNative.accessIndex(NodeTableNative.java:147)
        at org.apache.jena.tdb.store.nodetable.NodeTableNative._idForNode(NodeTableNative.java:120)
        at org.apache.jena.tdb.store.nodetable.NodeTableNative.getAllocateNodeId(NodeTableNative.java:76)
        at org.apache.jena.tdb.store.nodetable.NodeTableWrapper.getAllocateNodeId(NodeTableWrapper.java:40)
        at org.apache.jena.tdb.store.nodetable.NodeTableInline.getAllocateNodeId(NodeTableInline.java:51)
        at org.apache.jena.tdb.store.nodetupletable.NodeTupleTableConcrete.addRow(NodeTupleTableConcrete.java:85)
        at org.apache.jena.tdb.store.DatasetPrefixesTDB.insertPrefix(DatasetPrefixesTDB.java:62)
        at org.apache.jena.sparql.graph.GraphPrefixesProjection.setNsPrefix(GraphPrefixesProjection.java:41)
        at org.apache.jena.sparql.graph.GraphPrefixesProjection.lambda$setNsPrefixes$0(GraphPrefixesProjection.java:66)
        at java.util.HashMap$EntrySet.forEach(HashMap.java:1043)
        at org.apache.jena.sparql.graph.GraphPrefixesProjection.setNsPrefixes(GraphPrefixesProjection.java:65)
        at org.apache.jena.sparql.graph.GraphPrefixesProjection.setNsPrefixes(GraphPrefixesProjection.java:59)
        at org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.setNsPrefixes(ModelCom.java:1055)
        at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ContentAssembler$1.fill(ContentAssembler.java:146)
        at org.apache.jena.assembler.Content.fill(Content.java:62)
        at org.apache.jena.assembler.Content.fill(Content.java:62)
        at org.apache.jena.assembler.assemblers.ModelAssembler.addContent(ModelAssembler.java:54)
        ... 51 more
```

Thanks for your help :P

Comment: This was fixed in in Apache jena 3.11.0 : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1663. It is not to do with docker nor file access setting.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. It indeed  works well with latest jena fuseki version.